# How do i extrude multiple vertices without creating faces?

Tags: mesh, vertices

Im trying to sew together a quilt in Blender but filling vertices one at a time is tedious and im trying to find a better way to get something like this [image]

but when i fill more than two at a time i get this [image]

can someone tell me a less tedious solution?

Comment: Select both edges alignement and use 'bridge edge loops' from the 'edge' menu in edit mode.

Comment: Go with any method that creates faces, quickly, and then select the unwanted  faces by, say, Shift-G > Co-planar, and X > Delete Faces Only.

Comment: Thank you so much! this will save so much time!

Comment: You can also search for "Extrude Only Vertices and Move"